# jQuery dialog always opens top left

Tags: jquery-ui

My jQuery dialog always opens in the top left corner of my browser window.

The following shows my code after simplification.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id='submit' type="submit" value="Submit">
<div id='dialog'></div>
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(event){
    $(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width:500,
            height:500,
            position:'center'
        });
    });
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what I need to do so that it opens positioned in the center?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xGhAS/. On a side note, it's better practice to wrap your jQuery in a document ready call.

Comment: j08691, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 8):

It is <strike>highly</strike><sub>1</sub> unlikely that this is the cause of your problem, but I was having the same issue, and found this bit of code in jquery-ui.js :

```
// /1.10.0/jquery-ui.js:
target = $( options.of )
...
// line 12053 
if ( target[0].preventDefault ) {
    // force left top to allow flipping
    options.at = "left top";
}
```

That bit of code checks to see if the target element has the preventDefault function defined. By default, target[0] is going to equal the window object, which does not have preventDefault. However, in my case, I had defined a function called preventDefault in the window object's global scope. My window.preventDefault caused the if-block to evaluate to true, thus overriding the default options.at value of "center".

As I said, it's <strike>highly</strike><sub>1</sub>  unlikely that you have defined the function window.preventDefault, but that is what caused it for me.

<sup>1</sup> ***EDIT:*** based on the comments, it is actually not so unlikely. Glad I could help everyone.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was because of redefining window.preventDefault.

Comment: I guess it's not so highly unlikely that someone else would redefine window.preventDefault. Glad to hear I could help.

Comment: You just saved me many hours of frustration.  I found a plain old javascript function in global scope called preventDefault, which triggered this problem.  Much thanks!

Comment: Those who use JavaScripTools (http://javascriptools.sourceforge.net), a library I wrote a long time ago, will face this, as there is a global function called preventDefault (browser reality was very different at that time :-) ).
I had to hack it, by storing preventDefault in a temp variable, setting window.preventDefault = null, calling the dialog() method and then restoring the old function back.

Comment: Thanks! This was my situation! spent a few hours on this but with your post, I've search for preventDefault and found my issue. Great post!

Comment: I renamed that shit too.. seems like it's actually pretty likely.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<input id='submit' type="submit" value="Submit">
<div id='dialog'></div>
<script>
$('#submit').on('click', function(event){
    $(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            position:'center'
        });
    });
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
</script>​
```

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks MG_Bautista. However when I cut and post your code to replace mine, the dialog still opens top left even after I delete all my temporary browser files.

Comment: This is really weird; IE8 opens the dialog top left, Chrome opens it center center as expected, and FF opens it top center. Not good!!

Comment: Is there a way to ensure the dialog opens center center in all the major browsers? If I have not overlooked something, I thought that one of the main attractions with jQuery was that it addresses browser compatibility issues.

Comment: In order to center the dialog in all browsers I needed to add the following line.

`<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 1):

Use next dialog options

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width:500,
            height:500,
            position:
            {
               my: "center",
               at: "center",
               of: window
             }
        });
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjfet/)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is pretty simple, Just we need to add the jquery file jquery-1.11.1.js and it's all

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue where it would be centered in IE11, but on IE7 it would be top left corner even with the position attribute.

I am using jqueryUI 1.11.2, and it appears support for IE7 and older was removed in 1.8.2 or somewhere around there. Anyways, the solution was to put double quotes around my values like so:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: '200',
        title: 'Confirm Delete',
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: $("body"),
            within: $("body")
        },
        buttons: {
            'Delete': function () {
                $('#btnDeleteAll').click();
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

I just tried single quotes and those work too.